# Using Same Rails View for Many Products via Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, hyperlink, user-controls, rails-routing

I'm a rails newbie building my first application.  I've been learning a lot so far, but I'm hung up on the issue of trying to use the same view and populate it with information from my database when a particular product link is clicked.

So far I have a database of products.  On the front page of my site I list all products.  On this list, the name of each product is a link to the product details page.

The problem is there are many products, and they all have the same details, so I want to use a single view for the details page no matter which product link was clicked.  Basically, I need a way to tell my "productdetails" controller which link was clicked so it can retrieve the correct info from the product database via the model and pass it to the view...I can't seem to find a way to do this and I've been looking for several days.

Essentially, I have many links that I want to go to the same page, but have that page display differently depending on which link brought you there.  If you click the "Product 1" link you go to a page with "Product 1" at the top and details for that product.  If you click "Product 2" you go to an identical page with the title and details for Product 2, etc.

I realize I could just create a view and route for each link, but that seems silly, especially if I had 10,000 products!

Advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Relevant code is below.

Page Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def welcome
  end

  def front
    @securities = Security.find_securities
  end

  def userdetail
  end

  def securitydetail
    @securitynumber = params[:id]
  end
end
```

The Front Page view, where products are listed and links are made to detail pages...

```
<center><h2>FRONT PAGE</h2></center><div align=right><p><%= link_to "logout", :action => "welcome"-%></p></div>
<p>listing of available securities</p>

<p>
<% for security in @securities -%>
    <div class="entry">
        <h3><%= h link_to security.name, :action => "securitydetail" %></h3>
        <%= h security.description %>
        <div class="circulation">
            <span class="shares"><%= h security.shares %> Shares</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end -%>
```

The Product Details view, where I'm just trying to display a single unique ID for each product for the time being.  The variable comes from the page controller securitydetail action.

```
<h1><%= @securitynumber -%></h1>
```

Finally, here is the routing between the front page and the details page:

```
MarketVer2Apr2014::Application.routes.draw do
  get "listing/index"
  resources :securities

  get "pages/welcome"
  get "pages/front"
  #get "pages/userdetail"
  get "pages/securitydetail"

  root 'pages#welcome'
  get 'pages/front' => 'pages#front'
  #get 'pages/userdetail' => 'pages#userdetail'
  get 'pages/securitydetail' => 'pages#securitydetail'
```

I get all the routing, but need to get the information of what link was clicked into my controller...

Answer (score 1):

Your products should have their own product model, controllers, and views.  Your products controller with seven golden restful actions.  The show controller contains the info to render a single product

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def index
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

Then you can have a view in `views/products/show.html.erb` with whatever info you want to show such as the name of the product.  Rails will render the same view for each product.

```
<div class="name">
   <%= product.name %>
</div>
```

You should check out the Rails Routing Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html